# Access array property member with variable property name

Tags: php

In the context of a class method, what syntax is used to get the value of a array member using a variable property name?

```
class {

   private $aFruits=array('Apple'=>'Red','Banana'=>'Yellow','Orange'=>'Orange');

   public function MyFunction(){

      $PropName = 'aFruits';
      $KeyName = 'Banana';

      // Should be able to do something like:
      // Expected result: 'Yellow'
      return ${$this->$PropName}[$KeyName];    
   }
}
```

This syntax:

```
return ${$this->$PropName}[$KeyName];
```

...isn't quite right though, because it tries to convert `$this->$PropName` to a string to use as a variable name.

This syntax:

```
return $this->$PropName[$KeyName];
```

... Tries to use the value of `$PropName[$KeyName]` as the property name which is also incorrect.

There must be some way to get PHP to evaluate `$this->$PropName` first, and then get the `$KeyName` from the resultign array (without the use of an intermediary variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $this->$PropName[$KeyName];
```

This is the right approach, the only thing you need to do is delineate where your `$PropName` variable *ends* (i.e. whether it's `$PropName` or `$PropName[$KeyName]`). To do this, use:

```
return $this->{$PropName}[$KeyName];
```

Answer (score 1):

$Propname is not a property of $this but a local variable inside MyFunction() try:

```
return $this->{$PropName}[$KeyName];
```

Comment: NP, glad you got it sorted.